# error installing octave from source (qt4 unknown)

Tags: qt, octave

After I compile octave from source, I get the following error:

```
  GEN      libgui/src/qrc-resource.cc
Unknown option 'qt4'.
Makefile:27266: recipe for target 'libgui/src/qrc-resource.cc' failed
  CXX      libgui/graphics/libgui_graphics_libgui_graphics_la-__init_qt__.lo
make[2]: *** [libgui/src/qrc-resource.cc] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  GEN      libgui/graphics/moc-ToggleTool.cc
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yannik/octave-4.2.1'
Makefile:26135: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yannik/octave-4.2.1'
Makefile:9910: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I installed the libqt4 libraries though, so I don't know why this is happening. I've toiled for an hour and still have no idea why this would fail. Any thoughts?

Comment: what command you run to produce the above result? `./configure` and `make`...?